# I want to Pass Data in a Form to Codeignhter controller throught ajax. when I use this below code sometimes pass data and sometime doesn't

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

****I want to Pass my HTML Form Data in to Codeignhter controller throught ajax. when I check that data passed or not using var_dump() then someitmes it passed data and sometimes doesn't this is the code that I used..****

```
**jQuery Ajax Code**

$(document).ready(function () {
 
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
 
        //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
        event.preventDefault();
 
        // Get form
        var form = $('#myform')[0];
 
       // Create an FormData object 
        var data = new FormData(form);
 
       // If you want to add an extra field for the FormData
        data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");
 
       // disabled the submit button
        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: hosturl + "studentDetail",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 800000,
            success: function (data) {
 
                $("#output").text(data);
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
 
            },
            error: function (e) {
 
                $("#output").text(e.responseText);
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
 
            }
        });
 
    });
 
});
```

**CodeIgniter (Controller) file method code**

```
public function studentDetail_post()
    { 
              
       $stu = $this->input->post();
     var_dump($stu);
     die();
    }
```

**This is my HTML form code**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">

  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/><br/><br/>
  <input type="file" name="files"/><br/><br/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
```

pls give me a solution for this

Comment: Remove `var_dump` and replace with `echo json_endcode($stu);`

Comment: It's not working friend

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "name codeigniter controler/ name function of this controler",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            success : function(text){
                    console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            },
            
        });
```

and url: "/upload.php" is not studentDetail_post()

Comment: sorry it is a mistake when  I upload the question.I used this ' url: hosturl + "studentDetail",'

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: I used this data: $('#myform').serialize(), it worked. but It didn't pass the uploded files.I want to pass both text fileds data and the file

Comment: Uploaded files is not in $stu = $this->input->post();  Try var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: then how can I get normal text fields data